# How to hide item's template's subcontrol when not selected

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

This is the control I have bound to a collection.

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Pallets}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                <Button Content="C" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                <Button Content="D" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And this is how it looks like

[image]

What I would like to achieve is to have the two buttons (left and right) hidden by default, but should become visible on a selected item.

I suposse, it could be done using triggers?

Answer (score 0):

I got it myself

```
<Button Content="C" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger 
                    Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"
                    Value="False">

                    <Setter Property="Button.Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use binding and converter to achieve that.In your userControl declay this resource

```
<UserControl.Resources>       
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ListBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Pallets}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                <Button Content="C" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Visibility={Bindin Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},Converter{StaticResource BoolToVis }"}/>
                <Button Content="D" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Visibility={Bindin Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},Converter{StaticResource BoolToVis }"}/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**please note the was done live.I dont have acces to vs now to check the syntax**

Comment: Yeah, I dod Exactly that, already. Sorry for vasting your time, but thanx anyway